# Unable to access Django REST view

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am reading up a bit on the Django Rest Framework, but am finding it hard to implement. There is a page called "highscores.html" which, upon loading, should make a GET request to a RESTful service. which returns the list of high scores for that user. The relevant code is given below:

views.py:

```
from gamestore.serializers import ScoreSerializer
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
```

..

```
# display high scores
@api_view(['GET'])
def highscores(request, id):

        print("INSIDE HIGH SCORES")
        userobj = request.user
        gameobj = Games.objects.get(pk=id)
        scoreobj = Scores.objects.filter(game=gameobj, player=userobj)

        if request.method == 'GET':
                #print(scoreobj[0].game)
                serializer = ScoreSerializer(scoreobj)
                return Response(serializer.data, template_name='gamestore/highscores.html')
```

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Usertypes(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        usertype = models.TextField()

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.user_name

class Games(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
        category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        url = models.URLField()
        developer = models.ForeignKey(User)
        price = models.FloatField()

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

class Scores(models.Model):
        game = models.ForeignKey(Games)
        player = models.ForeignKey(User)
        registration_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
        gamestate = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        high_score_1 = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
        high_score_2 = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
        high_score_3 = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
        high_score_4 = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
        high_score_5 = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
        last_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)


        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.game
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from gamestore.models import Scores

    class ScoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

            class Meta:
                    model = Scores
                    fields = ('game', 'player', 'high_score_1', 'high_score_2', 'high_score_3', 'high_score_4', 'high_score_5')
```

highscores.html:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var game = $(this);
        var id = document.getElementById("gameid").value;
        alert(id);
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        $.ajax({
             type : "GET",
             url : "/highscores/",
             data : {'id': id},
             dataType : "json",
             success : function(data){
             console.log(data);
        }
        });
         event.preventDefault();
```

});

Actually, I am totally confused by the whole topic, and cannot understand how to render the Response in the "highscores" view in the highscore.html file. When I am running this with the server, I am getting a 404 Not Found error. The "highscores" view apparently is not even being accessed, as the "INSIDE HIGH SCORES" line is not showing in the server. As a tutorial, I followed this article, https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-rest-framework-quick-start/#drf-setup which seemed simple enough, but I do not understand many things like rendering the output, its format(e.g JSON) etc. Can someone please help? Even a link to an easy-to-understand-for-beginners document would be useful. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
import gamestore.views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        # Examples:
        # url(r'^$', 'wsdProject.views.home', name='home'),
        # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^$','gamestore.views.home'),
        url(r'^login/','gamestore.views.login_view'),
        url(r'^logout/','gamestore.views.logout_view'),
        url(r'^registration/','gamestore.views.registration'),
        url(r'^addgame/','gamestore.views.addgame'),
        url(r'^devhome/','gamestore.views.devhome'),
        url(r'^gamestats/','gamestore.views.gamestats'),
        url(r'^savegamestate/','gamestore.views.savegamestate'),
        url(r'^loadgamestate/','gamestore.views.loadgamestate'),
        url(r'^editgame/(?P<id>\d+)/','gamestore.views.editgame'),
        url(r'^delete/(?P<id>\d+)/','gamestore.views.deletegame'),
        url(r'^loadgame/(?P<id>\d+)/','gamestore.views.loadgame'),
        url(r'^loadhighscores/(?P<id>\d+)/','gamestore.views.loadhighscores'),
        url(r'^highscores/(?P<id>\d+)/','gamestore.views.highscores'),
        url(r'^gamestore/', include('gamestore.urls', namespace="gamestore")),
        url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
)
```

Comment: I think your urls.py file is not configured properly, can you put it in your question?

Comment: The urls file is added below.

Comment: you are requesting highscores by ajax but you are returning a html template as response, not a json one. be careful.

Comment: actually, in that tutorial link, they have returned it as json, but by defining another view "home". That's a part I am confused about. Is it necessary to create another view to return the JSON response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey, you have this url rule `url(r'^highscores/(?P<id>\d+)/'`.

So in your ajax call,  your url is just `"/highscores/"` and you are sending the `id` using `GET` parameters, so your final urls looks like `"/highscores/?id=some_id"` and that is wrong. Your url should looks like this `"/highscores/some_id"` . You need to append the id. `"/highscores/"+id`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                                var game = $(this);
                                var id = document.getElementById("gameid").value;
                                alert(id);
                                var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
                                $.ajax({
                                        type : "GET",
                                        url : "/highscores/"+id,

                                        dataType : "json",
                                        success : function(data){
                                                console.log(data);
                                        }
                                });
                                event.preventDefault();
                        });
```

Also, in your view, you are sending a html template as response, it should be `JSON` response. Just remove `template_name` parameter.

```
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: You are right, that at least prints the "INSIDE HIGH SCORES" line and so accesses the "highscores" view.

Comment: @user3033194 if answer helped you, you click on the check to mark as correct answer.

Comment: oh yes, I'll do that.